# What is the most efficient way to render a word game board in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, components, rendering

I am creating a multi-player word game in React. The game has a game board, composed of 18 by 18 cells (324 cells), and involves the players creating words, and laying them perpendicularly to each other, similar to Scrabble. There are several game tokens (called 'bonus cookies' and represented by SVGs) on the board, randomly generated and positioned when the game starts; these cookies and their positions are *part of the board*, and do not change throughout the game. On top of these cookies, and if the board object contains it, there can be a letter of the alphabet, similar to scrabble. The game object, served up by React-Query, contains a board object, which contains an 18 by 18 multi-dimensional array of cell objects that look similar to this:

```
{
row: 1,
col: 9,
letterTile: "F",
bonusCookieColor: "red",
bonusCookie: "three"
}
```

I have a `<PlayPage/>` React component, with a `<RenderBoard/>` child, which maps through the multi-dimensional board array, printing a CSS grid of `<RenderCell/>` components. And the RenderCell component, has/had a function with an extensive switch statement that looks like this:

```
function bonusCookieToRender(color: string, cookie: string): JSX.Element {
        let returnElement = <></>

        switch (color) {
            case "gold":
                switch (cookie) {
                    case "arrow":
                        returnElement = <TokenGoldArrow />
                        break
                    case "spinner":
                        returnElement = <TokenGoldSpinner />
                        break
                    case "ten":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold10 />
                        break
                    case "five":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold5 />
                        break
                    case "three":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold3 />
                        break
                    case "one":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold1 />
                        break
                    default:
                        returnElement = <></>
                }
                break
            case "red":
                switch (cookie) {
                    case "arrow":
                        returnElement = <TokenRedArrow />
                        break
                    case "spinner":
                        returnElement = <TokenRedSpinner />
                        break
                    case "ten":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed10 />
                        break
                    case "five":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed5 />
                        break
                    case "three":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed3 />
                        break
                    case "one":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed1 />
                        break
                    default:
                        returnElement = <></>
                }
                break
            case "blue":
                switch (cookie) {
                    case "arrow":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlueArrow />
                        break
                    case "spinner":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlueSpinner />
                        break
                    case "ten":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue10 />
                        break
                    case "five":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue5 />
                        break
                    case "three":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue3 />
                        break
                    case "one":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue1 />
                        break
                    default:
                        returnElement = <></>
                }
                break
        }
        return returnElement
    }
```

This function would run every single time the board would re-render (324 times per render). Clearly, this is not ideal, and considering the functionality I still need to add to the game, and the fact that multiple cells must be able to have hover effects (due to another component, which attaches Words to the mouse pointer, and allows players to drag the word around the board, lighting up multiple cells at a time), the amounts of rendering, is starting to show signs of slowness, and I fear it will only increase as I add functionality.

In the near future, in addition to having the cookie tokens, and the multi-cell hover, and the letters (also SVGs), if a letter is in a cell, I will need to be able to show a smaller (20%ish) version of the cookie, in the lower right hand corner on top of a letter tile, so the player knows which cookie token is under the letter this cell. In addition to all of this, there will be another feature, which allows a player to 'split' certain words, which will require calculating whether or not there is enough room to split a word (with all of its other attached words, horizontal and vertical, etc), and then animating the necessary letters into their new positions to complete the play (if they CAN be moved, according to the rules, etc).

So, the reason I wrote all of this, is to help the reader understand that there are quite a few calculations happening, and all of them, as the user hovers from cell to cell to cell. Each move from one cell to another, is going to have to start a series of calculations, which could be expensive. The current RenderBoard component looks like this:

```
const RenderBoard = ({ boardToRender }: any) => {
    const setHoverPointerCoordinates = useSetAtom(hoverPointerCoordinatesAtom)
    const setHoverCoordinates = useSetAtom(hoverCoordinatesAtom)
    const setHoverPointerCookie = useSetAtom(hoverPointerCookieAtom)
    const setHoverCookies = useSetAtom(hoverCookiesAtom)
    const numberOfLettersInWord = useAtomValue(chosenWordLengthAtom)

    function handleMouseOut() {
        setHoverPointerCoordinates({})
        setHoverCoordinates([])
        setHoverPointerCookie({})
        setHoverCookies([])
    }
    return (
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
            {/* // layer 1 */}
            <div className="overflow-auto flex justify-center py-8 absolute">
                <div
                    key={"main-board-box"}
                    className="grid grid-rows-[repeat(18,_minmax(0,_1fr))] h-min border-4 border-slate-800"
                    onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
                >
                    {boardToRender?.map((row: any, indexRow: number) => (
                        <div
                            key={`row-${indexRow.toString()}`}
                            className="flex"
                        >
                            {row.map((cell: any, indexCell: number) => (
                                <div
                                    key={`row-${indexRow.toString()}-cell-${indexCell.toString()}`}
                                    className="border border-slate-800 flex justify-center items-center w-[46px] h-[46px]"
                                >
                                    <RenderCell cell={cell} />
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
            
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default RenderBoard
```

and the RenderCell component looks like this:

```
const RenderCell = React.memo((props: any) => {
    const { cell } = props

    const authMeQueryData = useAuthMe()
    const currentGame = useCurrentGame(authMeQueryData.data?.currentGameId)

    const setHoverPointerCoordinates = useSetAtom(hoverPointerCoordinatesAtom)
    const setHoverCoordinates = useSetAtom(hoverCoordinatesAtom)
    const setHoverPointerCookie = useSetAtom(hoverPointerCookieAtom)
    const setHoverCookies = useSetAtom(hoverCookiesAtom)
    const [cellHoverStates, setCellHoverStates] = useAtom(cellHoverStatesAtom)
    const cellHoverStatesReset = useAtomValue(cellHoverStatesResetAtom)
    const chosenWordLength = useAtomValue(chosenWordLengthAtom)

    const handleMouseOver = (currentRow: number, currentCol: number, currentCookieColor: string, currentCookie: string) => {
        updateCellHoverStates(currentRow, currentCol)

        setHoverPointerCoordinates({ row: currentRow, col: currentCol })
        setHoverPointerCookie({ color: currentCookieColor, cookie: currentCookie })

        const coordinateArray = []
        const cookieArray = []
        for (let count = 0; count <= chosenWordLength - 1; count++) {
            coordinateArray.push({ row: currentRow, col: currentCol + count })
            cookieArray.push({
                color: currentGame?.data?.board[currentRow][currentCol + count]?.bonusCookieColor,
                cookie: currentGame?.data?.board[currentRow][currentCol + count]?.bonusCookie,
            })
        }
        setHoverCoordinates(coordinateArray)
        setHoverCookies(cookieArray)
    }

    const handleMouseLeave = () => resetCellHoverStates()

    const updateCellHoverStates = (row: number, col: number) => {
        for (let count = 0; count <= chosenWordLength - 1; count++) {
            setCellHoverStates((prevCellHoverStates: any) => {
                const rowIndexToSet = row
                const colIndexToSet = addWithCeiling(col, count, 17)
                const newStates = [...prevCellHoverStates]
                newStates[rowIndexToSet] = [...newStates[rowIndexToSet]]
                newStates[rowIndexToSet][colIndexToSet] = true
                return newStates
            })
        }
    }

    const resetCellHoverStates = () => {
        setCellHoverStates(cellHoverStatesReset)
    }

    function bonusCookieToRender(color: string, cookie: string): JSX.Element {
        let returnElement = <></>

        switch (color) {
            case "gold":
                switch (cookie) {
                    case "arrow":
                        returnElement = <TokenGoldArrow />
                        break
                    case "spinner":
                        returnElement = <TokenGoldSpinner />
                        break
                    case "ten":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold10 />
                        break
                    case "five":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold5 />
                        break
                    case "three":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold3 />
                        break
                    case "one":
                        returnElement = <TokenGold1 />
                        break
                    default:
                        returnElement = <></>
                }
                break
            case "red":
                switch (cookie) {
                    case "arrow":
                        returnElement = <TokenRedArrow />
                        break
                    case "spinner":
                        returnElement = <TokenRedSpinner />
                        break
                    case "ten":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed10 />
                        break
                    case "five":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed5 />
                        break
                    case "three":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed3 />
                        break
                    case "one":
                        returnElement = <TokenRed1 />
                        break
                    default:
                        returnElement = <></>
                }
                break
            case "blue":
                switch (cookie) {
                    case "arrow":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlueArrow />
                        break
                    case "spinner":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlueSpinner />
                        break
                    case "ten":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue10 />
                        break
                    case "five":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue5 />
                        break
                    case "three":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue3 />
                        break
                    case "one":
                        returnElement = <TokenBlue1 />
                        break
                    default:
                        returnElement = <></>
                }
                break
        }
        return returnElement
    }

    function letterTileToRender(letterTile: string): JSX.Element {
        let returnElement = <></>

        if (letterTile && typeof letterTile === "string") letterTile = letterTile.toUpperCase()

        switch (letterTile) {
            case "A":
                returnElement = <LetterTileA />
                break
            case "B":
                returnElement = <LetterTileB />
                break
            case "C":
                returnElement = <LetterTileC />
                break
            case "D":
                returnElement = <LetterTileD />
                break
            case "E":
                returnElement = <LetterTileE />
                break
            case "F":
                returnElement = <LetterTileF />
                break
            case "G":
                returnElement = <LetterTileG />
                break
            case "H":
                returnElement = <LetterTileH />
                break
            case "I":
                returnElement = <LetterTileI />
                break
            case "J":
                returnElement = <LetterTileJ />
                break
            case "K":
                returnElement = <LetterTileK />
                break
            case "L":
                returnElement = <LetterTileL />
                break
            case "M":
                returnElement = <LetterTileM />
                break
            case "N":
                returnElement = <LetterTileN />
                break
            case "O":
                returnElement = <LetterTileO />
                break
            case "P":
                returnElement = <LetterTileP />
                break
            case "Q":
                returnElement = <LetterTileQ />
                break
            case "R":
                returnElement = <LetterTileR />
                break
            case "S":
                returnElement = <LetterTileS />
                break
            case "T":
                returnElement = <LetterTileT />
                break
            case "U":
                returnElement = <LetterTileU />
                break
            case "V":
                returnElement = <LetterTileV />
                break
            case "W":
                returnElement = <LetterTileW />
                break
            case "X":
                returnElement = <LetterTileX />
                break
            case "Y":
                returnElement = <LetterTileY />
                break
            case "Z":
                returnElement = <LetterTileZ />
                break
            default:
                break
        }

        return returnElement
    }

    return (
        <div
            className={`${
                cellHoverStates[cell.row - 1][cell.col - 1] ? "bg-emerald-300" : "bg-slate-300"
            } flex justify-center items-center w-[46px] h-[46px]`}
            onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(cell.row - 1, cell.col - 1, cell.bonusCookieColor, cell.bonusCookie)}
            onMouseLeave={() => handleMouseLeave()}
        >
            <div className="select-none">
                {cell?.letterTile ? letterTileToRender(cell?.letterTile) : bonusCookieToRender(cell.bonusCookieColor, cell.bonusCookie)}                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
})

export default RenderCell
```

I have only been working with React for a couple years now, but I am certain this cannot be the best way to do this. So, I tried modifying the bonus cookie part like this:

```
const bonusCookieToRenderMemorized = useMemo(() => {
        const boardSize = 18
        const arrayToReturn = []
        console.log({ boardToRender })
        for (let rowCount = 0; rowCount <= boardSize - 1; rowCount++) {
            const rowArrayToPush: JSX.Element[] = []
            for (let colCount = 0; colCount <= boardSize - 1; colCount++) {
                let returnElement = <></>
                const color = boardToRender[rowCount][colCount].bonusCookieColor
                const cookie = boardToRender[rowCount][colCount].bonusCookie
                console.log(color, cookie)
                switch (color) {
                    case "gold":
                        switch (cookie) {
                            case "arrow":
                                returnElement = <TokenGoldArrow />
                                break
                            case "spinner":
                                returnElement = <TokenGoldSpinner />
                                break
                            case "ten":
                                returnElement = <TokenGold10 />
                                break
                            case "five":
                                returnElement = <TokenGold5 />
                                break
                            case "three":
                                returnElement = <TokenGold3 />
                                break
                            case "one":
                                returnElement = <TokenGold1 />
                                break
                            default:
                                returnElement = <></>
                        }
                        break
                    case "red":
                        switch (cookie) {
                            case "arrow":
                                returnElement = <TokenRedArrow />
                                break
                            case "spinner":
                                returnElement = <TokenRedSpinner />
                                break
                            case "ten":
                                returnElement = <TokenRed10 />
                                break
                            case "five":
                                returnElement = <TokenRed5 />
                                break
                            case "three":
                                returnElement = <TokenRed3 />
                                break
                            case "one":
                                returnElement = <TokenRed1 />
                                break
                            default:
                                returnElement = <></>
                        }
                        break
                    case "blue":
                        switch (cookie) {
                            case "arrow":
                                returnElement = <TokenBlueArrow />
                                break
                            case "spinner":
                                returnElement = <TokenBlueSpinner />
                                break
                            case "ten":
                                returnElement = <TokenBlue10 />
                                break
                            case "five":
                                returnElement = <TokenBlue5 />
                                break
                            case "three":
                                returnElement = <TokenBlue3 />
                                break
                            case "one":
                                returnElement = <TokenBlue1 />
                                break
                            default:
                                returnElement = <></>
                        }
                        break
                }
                rowArrayToPush.push(returnElement)
            }
            arrayToReturn.push(rowArrayToPush)
        }
        return arrayToReturn
    }, [boardToRender])
```

and then, instead of printing the bonus cookie, in the RenderCell component, I would print it in the RenderBoard component with code similar to this:

```
{ bonusCookieToRenderMemorized[indexRow][indexCell] }
    }
```

Just so I didn't have to have that huge switch statement each time.

To sum this all up, the question I am trying to ask is this. Considering the manner in which React re-renders (which again, I am not an expert on), and what I need to DO (my requirements), which do you think would be the most efficient and WHY???:

1. The way I am doing it currently, with the RenderBoard, following by 324 RenderCells, everything printed being switched in this component?
2. Drop the RenderCells completely, and just have a RenderBoard component, then useMemo() any 'grid like' structures I need in the RenderBoard component, and just print them out
3. (and I haven't talked about this, but knowing my requirements) Maybe I should separate the board, into multiple 'layers', all on top of each other, each in a different component. One for the hover effects, one for the tokens, one for the letters, one for the smaller letters, and then one for the  'splitting' triggers (mentioned earlier), so that when something changes, it can only render the layer that changed...

OR am I thinking about this all wrong, and there is a way better way to do it. :) Thanks in advance for any advice anyone may offer.

Comment: What's `useSetAtom`,  I've heard of `useAtom` from Jotia, and that would be my suggestion too, don't place state in HOC, it's a performance killer, and `React.memo` would only be plastering over the problem.   Just have your board made up of an array of atoms, performance should then be fine.  To make life easier I would also place your array of atoms in a Context.

Comment: "The most efficient way" is a pretty broad and ambiguous term.

Comment: useSetAtom is the same as useAtom, but instead of returning the tuple, it just returns the setter... i actually MEANT to take the react.memo around RenderCell out, as I had already realized it was pointless. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I agree 'most efficient' is broad, my apologies, the point of the question was to hopefully get someone more familiar with React's re-rendering behavior to maybe give me some tips. I will be more precise in the future.

Comment: I would probably go with configurable cookie component, like `<Token color="gold" shape="spinner" size="small">`, and just feed the right props into each one.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).